# How Africans use their wages?

Tags: data-request, money, wages, poverty, saving

I was researching poverty in Africa and was reading about their daily wages. 
Based on the article linked, **2/3 of Africans live on less than $1.25 USD, a day**.

However, what this article and many other ones don't elaborate on is how that $1.25 is used.

I would like to better understand how African families use their money, and am especially interested to learn how much money goes into *savings*. For example, maybe 1 dollar is used for food and other necessities, and other $0.25 is kept as savings.

If anyone has any answers or data that may help answer this question, I appreciate any help. Thanks.

Link: 
http://global-growing.org/en/content/fact-7-about-three-quarters-african-population-live-less-2-half-population-less-125-day

Comment: Your linked article actually says  51 per cent of sub-Saharan Africans live on  $1.25 (€0.94) per day.  That is rather out of date.  For example the [World Bank](http://povertydata.worldbank.org/poverty/region/SSF) say that in 2013 42.3% of the population below $1.90 a day (2011 PPP) and the proportion may have fallen since then.  At that level, saving is likely to be minimal, except for buying the odd animal

Comment: You're right, the data's outdated. However, I was still looking to understand what percent of wages goes into their savings. Do you have any data for that? You may be right, but I have yet to find any evidence, so it's only an assumption right now.

Comment: Just something I would like to add. Looking at Africans as a homogeneous groups is really going to impact any sort of economic analysis. Maybe reconsider your question in terms of a single SSA country.

Comment: Good point, different locations and groups probably differ significantly. However, I think I shouldn't to be too picky simply because of the rarity of this kind of data. At this moment, anything helps :)

Comment: What's savings?  If someone takes \$10 and buys a goat for milk and potentially for food, how should that appear?  Is it an investment (savings)?  Consumption?  Food (milk and meat)?  What if it's a billy goat to add to five females?  No milk value and kept for breeding rather than eating.   Then someone buys seeds for \$2.  It will eventually be food, but it's currently an investment.  I suspect most Africans grow or raise food, buying tools and animals as they can.  I.e. I suspect that paying \$1 for ready-to-cook food is not how it works.